# Monocular Total Capture compilation make error : fatal error: glm/glm.hpp: File or directory not found

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to use this repo :

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/MonocularTotalCapture

These are the packages that I have installed :

```
ffmpeg
Python 2.7.12 (with TensorFlow 1.5.0, OpenCV, Matplotlib, packages installed with pip3)
openCV 4.2.0
cmake = 3.5.1
OpenCV 2.4.13 (compiled from source with CUDA 9.0, CUDNN 7.0)
Ceres-Solver 1.13.0 (with SuiteSparse)
OpenGL, GLUT, GLEW
libigl https://github.com/libigl/libigl
wget
OpenPose
eigen3, version 3.3.7
Boost version: 1.58.0
GNU 5.4.0
```

unfortunately I get an error at the end and I don't know how to fix.

```
mario@ziom-Z87-HD3:/home/ziom/Scrivania/MonocularTotalCapture/FitAdam/build# make -k

/home/ziom/Scrivania/MonocularTotalCapture/FitAdam/src/Renderer.cpp:5:23: fatal error: glm/glm.hpp: File o directory not found

....

/home/ziom/Scrivania/MonocularTotalCapture/FitAdam/src/AdamFastCost.cpp:1225:29: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
for (int ic = 0; ic < total_vertex.size(); ic++)
^
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MYLIB.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Try installing the `libglm-dev` package (or whatever your distro calls it).

Comment: bingo. this was was missing.